# Partition functions for a (3+1)-d TQFT

Tags: conformal-field-theory, topological-field-theory, topological-order, chern-simons-theory

It is well known that for a Chern-Simons theory defined on an arbitrary (2+1)-d oriented manifold, its partition function can be evaluated based on Witten's surgery method.

My question is: is there a parallel story in a higher dimension, such as (3+1)-d? Thanks for any comments/suggestions!

PS: In a recent interesting paper: [Wang-Wen-Yau](http://arxiv.org/abs/1602.05951), the surgery procedure in (3+1)-d manifold is discussed. But I am still curious how one can calculate the partition function explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TQFTs by definition satisfy cutting and gluing axioms. Roughly speaking, you should be able to obtain the partition function of the TQFT on a general (closed) manifold by cutting the manifold into small, elementary pieces which we understand, and then the partition function can be calculated from assembling the pieces together. This holds very generally in any dimensions. In fact, the strongest version of cutting and gluing is that one can decompose the manifold all the way down to a "point", which in practice means that the TQFT is some kind of state sum of a triangulation of the manifold. In such cases, the computation of the partition function becomes a combinatoric problem. Mathematically TQFTs satisfying this nice property are called fully extended. In fact all known TQFTs in 3+1D are fully extended (Crane-Yetter TQFT, and Dijkgraaf-Witten gauge theories).

Chern-Simons theories in 2+1 are generally not fully extended, but they still satisfy cutting and gluing. There are also things beyond simply cutting and gluing that are more specific to 2+1 (i.e. putting a knot into S^3). It is not clear whether in 3+1 there are similar results, since we do not currently fully understand the algebraic structure of 3+1 TQFT.